# Oracle connection info - risks?

Tags: oracle, security

An Oracle security question..

There are several pieces of data used for Oracle connections, like: host, port, TNS, SID, user, etc

Obviously user/password cannot be shared, what is the data sensitivity regarding the other items? **i.e. if someone had the sid/user could they do harm ?**

Comment: ALL of that information is sensitive and should not be shared.

Comment: cool dude. maybe we should just hand out etch-a-sketches to our users, and keep all our systems safe by not using them. 

some degree of inventory & reporting is obviously needed

Comment: Helping to give away your data by exposing sensitive connection details is _not_ a convenience: it is a lawsuit and/or criminal charges waiting to happen. It is contrary - literally - to every security best practice ever written.

Comment: The principle of least privilege always applies. Share what you need to with the people who absolutely _need_ to know, and no more. Keep the inventory information in a place where you can control and audit access to it, so that it doesn't get shared beyond your intent. Only share usernames with the actual users and don't use shared accounts/credentials. Only share SID or service_name info with the people who need to access that particular database. Follow CIS, STIG, or whatever regulatory guidelines for security apply to your systems and document everything.

Answer (score 1):

Every cyber attack starts with a phase called "reconnaissance", when your goal is to discover everything you can about the target. So yes, by allowing SIDs and USERNAMEs to be public, you're making things easier for an attacker.

For example, if I wanted to brute force your database for a connection, having that information makes things a lot easier for me. I already have a username and a service, so all I need is a list of passwords to start the attack.